# Get text colour of navigation bar title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I need to **get** the text colour of a navigation bar title.

I know how to set it using:

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = ...`

However, I can't seem to find anything that actually **gets** the colour rather than setting it. I have tried using:

`NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes);`

which prints out a dictionary containing the `titleTextAttributes`. One entry in it has the key `NSColor`, however, its value doesn't seem to actually match the colour of the text. This output looks like:

```
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fa23be1df60> font-family: \"HelveticaNeue\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 24.00pt";
}
```

Anyone have any idea how to retrieve this information?

Comment: Update your question with the log output of the title attributes.

Comment: Added it as requested.

Comment: That is the color white.

Comment: Yes, but the colour of the text is actually black.

Comment: Strange. Black should be `UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1` I believe.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Didn't realise that the numbers on the end represented the colour. Saw 'White' in the name and just made an assumption. Silly me! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I had written above for retrieving the colour that I thought wasn't working **is** actually correct. That is:

```
 NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes = self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes;
```

This retrieves a dictionary with the titles text properties in it.
One of the entries in this dictionary has the key `NSColor` of which its value is the actual colour of the text. This can be specifically retrieved using:

```
UIColor *textColor = [self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes objectForKey:@"NSColor"];
```

**Note:**
Colours black and white are listed as `UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1` or `UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1` respectively. Do not be confused that both have 'white' in their name as I was.

Thanks to [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) for pointing this out.